# iPad open file with external program

Tags: ipad, file, external, uidocumentinteraction

Help me pleas. I need to find some way to open files with external application on iPad.

More detail:
I run my program and have a file that I have to open with external application.
I need to get a list of programs installed on iPad, chose one of them and then open file with in.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [example application available](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052) from Apple that shows you how to preview documents. To achieve what you want you will have to look at the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, it's probably best if you start reading [this overview article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403).